# Show C++ program console output after Windows boot

Tags: c++, windows

I've searched everywhere I can think of for the answer, but this seems to be a rather unique problem...

I wrote a C++ program that outputs using the typical std::cout. I compiled it using MinGW, and it functions as one might expect. I plan for this program to run at Windows startup, so I added the program to the Local Group Policy Editor's startup scripts. Upon testing, the program does indeed run in the background when Windows boots, but since Windows displays the Welcome/Lock screen first, the console window doesn't popup and show output.

Obviously for security reasons, it makes sense that the console window doesn't appear on top of the Welcome/Lock screen, but after logging in, the console window still doesn't show up, and the program remains running behind the scenes. I was hoping there might be some function call in the Windows API that I could make after login that would make the console window appear.

I could configure Windows to run the program on login instead (which displays the console window output correctly), but it's not the ideal solution. Any thought's/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how well it works past XP, but it was possible using a service and running the process on the logon desktop.

Comment: Try [GetConsoleWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [SetForegroundWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The only thing to determine is the right moment to call it.

Comment: It's a secure desktop (or was meant to be). I think the Gina scheme was discontinued in Windows Vista. But that's where I'd start searching, except that I would try my damnedest to *avoid* running something at startup.

Comment: @Drop that was a good idea, and I just tried it in my code, but it didn't fix the problem. I'm was able to pick up when someone logged in by doing a repeated GetUserName() check, but it seems like there's might not be any console window to do GetConsoleWindow() on, so nothing showed up. I'll keep tinkering with it though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf GINA was indeed discontinued in Vista, and this needs to work on both Windows 7 and 8 machines. Thanks for the tip though.